# Simple Menu not starting on new line -- BootStrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to learn bootstrap and very fustrated with the basics 
I have this menu.  When it is in mobile mode the three stack bars appear but the menu starts on the header row.  The desired result is to start on the row below the header.  What class did I miss or what am I doing in correctly

Thanks for your help.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7o2nr82d/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap 3</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Mike's Site</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- do we need collapse and navbar-collapse-->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Social Media</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this, I've added a ul definition for the navbar right.  Changed the way to call the data-target (still new so don't know if it was required or not)

```
    <div class="navbar navbar=default navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Mike's Site</a>

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collaspe" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

             <!--do we need collapse and navbar-collapse-->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Social Media</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Social Media</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you searching around on the web I found this: A recent update to Bootstrap 3 now requires that you wrap the nav-brand and your responsive drop down button in a div with a class of .navbar-header. The code on my website will soon be updated to reflect these changes.  I added that extra div under container and it works.  I will have to look into container-fluid and whether to use Id's vs classes for data-target.  Thank you.